# Parameters from observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parameters, key-value-observing

I was wondering what the parameters from this method would return.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change
                        context:(void *)context;
```

In [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:) it says

> *keyPath* The key path, relative to object, to the value that has changed.
>
> *object* The source object of the key path keyPath.
>
> *change* A dictionary that describes the changes that have been made to the
> value of the property at the key path
> keyPath relative to object.
>
> *context* The value that was provided when the receiver was registered to
> receive key-value observation
> notifications.

Could you possibly explain these parameters for me, as i find the documentation a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you registered for KVO notifications you specified a keypath to `addObserver:`. The keypath parameter is simply this value being returned to you. The object parameter is the object to which you sent the `addObserver:` message. These can be used to differentiate between KVO notifications of different keypaths/objects (for instance if you're observing multiple values).

`change` is a dictionary that contains information about the nature of the value change. It might contain the new value or the old value or, for to-many relationships, it might contain the indices that changed. Its contents are better described in the [KVO Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252) in the *Receiving Notification of a Change* section.

When you register for the notification you can also specify a context value. The last value is simply this value returned to you. If you don't have any context-specific information, passing nil to `addObserver:` is appropriate.

For a good discussion on some shortcomings of the KVO system (and some helper classes to address them), see [Mike Ash's great blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html)

Comment: Just note about the KVO link, it has moved to here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html