# What is the context parameter used for in Key value observing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

What's the use of context parameter in following method which is used  to register for key value notifications. The documentations just denotes it as arbitrary set of data.

```
addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedIndex" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil
```

Can somebody shed some light what's the purpose behind it ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameters from observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625575/parameters-from-observevalueforkeypathofobjectchangecontext)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I hope this explanation isn't too abstract to understand.

Suppose you create a class `MyViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`.  You don't have the source code of `UIViewController`.

Now you decide to make `MyViewController` use KVO to observe changes to the `center` property of `self.view`.  So you duly add yourself as an observer:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:0 context:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center"];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

The problem here is that you don't know if `UIViewController` also registers itself as an observer of `self.view`'s `center`.  If it does, then you might have two problems:

1. You might be called twice when the view's center changes.
2. When you remove yourself as an observer, you might also remove `UIViewController`'s KVO registration.

You need a way to register yourself as an observer that is distinguishable from `UIViewController`'s KVO registration.  That's where the `context` argument comes in.  You need to pass a value for `context` that you are absolutely sure `UIViewController` is *not* using as the `context` argument.  When you unregister, you use the same `context` again so that you only remove your registration, not `UIViewController`'s registration.  And in your `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method, you need to check the `context` to see if the message is for you, or for your superclass.

One way to be sure you use a `context` that nothing else uses is to create a `static` variable in `MyViewController.m`.  Use it when you register and unregister, like this:

```
static int kCenterContext;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:0 context:&kCenterContext];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" context:&kCenterContext];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Then in your `observeValueForKeyPath:...` method, check it like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == &kCenterContext) {
        // This message is for me.  Handle it.
        [self viewCenterDidChange];
        // Do not pass it on to super!
    } else {
        // This message is not for me; pass it on to super.
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
            change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Now you're guaranteed not to interfere with your superclass's KVO, if it does any.  And if somebody makes a subclass of `MyViewController` that also uses KVO, it won't interfere with your KVO.

Note too that you can use a different context for each key path you observe.  Then, when the system notifies you of a change, you can check the context instead of checking the key path.  Testing for pointer equality is a little faster than checking for string equality.  Example:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == &kCenterContext) {
        [self viewCenterDidChange];
        // Do not pass it on to super!
    } else if (context == &kBackgroundColorContext) {
        [self viewBackgroundDidChange];
        // Do not pass it on to super!
    } else if (context == &kAlphaContext) {
        [self viewAlphaDidChange];
        // Do not pass it on to super!
    } else {
        // This message is not for me; pass it on to super.
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
            change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your detailed explanation.Really appreciate it. It's been puzzling me for some time why this parameter is important and your answered clarified it. :)

Comment: Hello can I use context to set some objects and later when the notification come retrieve it o perform some specific tasks based on the value stored in context.

Comment: +1 Brilliant explanation. (One single caveat: `UIView`'s properties are not KVO compliant. You can't observe `view.center`.)

Comment: @robmayoff so this is the only case?

Comment: @onmyway133 It is also slightly faster to dispatch based on context instead of on key path.  I have updated my answer.