# How to use "context" in " observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:"

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

Having read KVO guide, KVC guide, KVO protocol ref, I have never seen a solid example on how/when to use the last parameter of observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

the description on this "context" is so vague in Apple's document, so are the examples through KVO/KVC!

Can anyone point it out for me? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importance of context parameter in Key value observing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916502/importance-of-context-parameter-in-key-value-observing)

Comment: Sven, thanks! I got it.