# How to deal with a void* cast under ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Under ARC, I create a NSDictionary which I assign to a property. Then I set it as the void* context parameter of KVO:

```
[obj addObserver:self 
      forKeyPath:kp 
         options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
         context:(void*)dict];
```

The [KVO programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) states that:

> Note: The key-value observing addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
>   method does not maintain strong references to the observing object,
>   the observed objects, or the context. You should ensure that you
>   maintain strong references to the observing, and observed, objects,
>   and the context as necessary.

So it does not hold a strong reference to dict. I think ARC has no problem with this because it is just an argument.

When I get the callback I extract the dictionary like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                       context:(void *)context {

    NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)context;
    //...

}
```

So I remember there were **catches with ARC and void*** and I think it was to use __bridge when you cast a void* to an Objective-C object pointer type when you wouldn't have to call **-release** in manual retain counting code. Because I didn't create ownership here I just do __bridge so ARC won't overrelease it.

But do I have to do something special for ARC to SET the dictionary as argument? Xcode doesn't complain but I have a feeling something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Basically context is not for passing an object, just to pass an identifier (such as an address) so that the specific item can be identified.

This is different from `NSNotification` that can pass an object declared as: `object:(id)anObject`, not `context:(void *)context`.

From [SO answer by @nall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625631/451475):

> When you register for the notification you can also specify a context
>   value. The last value is simply this value returned to you. If you
>   don't have any context-specific information, passing nil to
>   addObserver: is appropriate.

See: [Mike Ash on "context"](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html)

Comment: I agree that the context is meant for passing an identifier (address or constant string). It is still strange that the ARC compiler does not require a *bridged* cast `... context:(bridge void *)dict]` when converting from an Objective-C type to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your basic assumption is wrong, in that arc doesn't care about void * at all and you also aren't passing a reference to an object(in this context it is just a pointer)... ARC has no work to do there.